# current_timestamp redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-redshift

When I select `current_timestamp` from redshift, I am getting a list of values instead of one value.

Here is my SQL query

```
select current_timestamp 
from stg.table;
```

Does anybody know why I am getting a list of values instead a single value?

Comment: What did you expect? You are select all rows from the table `stg.table` but you are displaying a constant value ("current_timestamp") for each of them.

Comment: oh man you right. I want to get only one value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select current_timestamp from stg.table
```

This produces as many rows as there are in table `stg.table` (since that's the `from` clause), with a single column that always contains the current date/time on each row. On the other hand, if the table contains no row, the query returns no rows.

If you want just one row, use a scalar subquery without a `from` clause:

```
select current_timestamp as my_timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

You will receive a row for each row in stg.table. According to the RedShift docs you should be using GETDATE() or SYSDATE() instead. Perhaps you want, e.g.:

```
select GETDATE() as my_timestamp
```